# Whitespaces on the right side dont matter when comparing

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

```
DEFINE VARIABLE a AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE b AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
a = "123".
b = "123 ".

MESSAGE a = b
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

MESSAGE LENGTH(a) = LENGTH(b)
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Does anyone know, why the first equals returns true?
Are whitespaces ignored on the right side? Because a whitespace on the left would cause the equals to be false. It also doesn't matter how many whitespaces there are on the right side.

Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/eq-or-=-operator.html

> The equal comparison ignores trailing blanks. Thus, "abc" is equal to "abc ". However, leading and embedded blanks are treated as characters and " abc" is not equal to "abc".

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's just the way the ABL is implemented.

You can use the COMPARE function.

```
MESSAGE a = b SKIP 
        COMPARE (a, "EQ", b, "RAW")
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```